# CodeIgniter pagination library does not load on a particular controller

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination, php-5.3

CodeIgniter's pagination library is not loading in a particular controller of my project, the same piece of code works fine in other controllers of the same project.

Here is the code that loads correctly: (controller name : Purchases)

```
    // load pagination library
    $this->load->library('pagination');

    //configure pagination
    $page_config['base_url']         = base_url('purchases/list_all');
    $page_config['total_rows']       = $total_no_of_purs;
    $page_config['per_page']         = $no_of_purs_per_page;
    $page_config['uri_segment']      = 3;
    $page_config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;

    //initialize pagination
    $this->pagination->initialize($page_config);
```

and Here follows the code that fails to load pagination library (Controller Name: Employee)

```
    //load pagination library
    $this->load->library('pagination');

    //configure pagination
    $page_config['base_url']         = base_url('employee/list_all');
    $page_config['total_rows']       = $total_no_of_emps;
    $page_config['per_page']         = $no_of_emps_per_page;
    $page_config['uri_segment']      = 3;
    $page_config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;

    //initialize pagination
    $this->pagination->initialize($page_config);
```

I want to say that all the variables assigned to the config are valid. The error I am getting for the second piece of code is:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Undefined property: Employee::$pagination
Filename: controllers/employee.php
Line Number: 115
```

Line 115 is: `$this->load->library('pagination');`

In both the classes, the constructor was not loaded with the pagination library.  Why does one work and the other not?

Comment: what is your line 115?

Comment: Can you try to autoload (`application\config\autoload.php`) the pagination library, instead to loading in every controller.  Give it a try.

Comment: this is my 115th line    $this->load->library('pagination');

Comment: @ArifulHaque , Yes, now I tried Autoloading the library, now the prblm is $this->pagination->create_links(); is not working, leaving no error. :'(

Comment: can you share you `Employee` controller? use http://pastebin.com/ to share

Comment: That may not be the actual problem. What does your error.log say?

Answer (score 0):

`$this->pagination->create_links();` only shows pagination when your `$total_no_of_emps` is greater than `$no_of_emps_per_page`.

Answer (score 0):

this error because of

`$page_config['base_url'] = base_url('employee/list_all');`

try this `$page_config['base_url'] = base_url()."employee/list_all";` If not

** you need to define `base_url();` first

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your coding related to pagination, I want to see your whole controller of employee as seems that extends  in employee controller is missing and hence they are not able to load pagination class and hence please paste your complete employee controller here.

Thanks,
Shankar